# Win service not stopped and uninstalled during upgrade

Tags: windows, service, wix, windows-installer, major-upgrade

I am having an issue with an installer built with Wix 3.7. I have a product which install a Windows Service.
The problem is that during a product upgrade (from version 1.1 to version 1.2, same UpgradeCode, different ProductCode Guid and MajorUpgrade property used) I want to replace the executable ran by the Service. The file is in use by the old process (i.e. the Windows service).
I suspect that the 1.1 installer is used to uninstall the 1.1 product, and in that installer the ServiceControl was invalid (i.e. not set to stop on uninstall).

My guess:

1. 1.2 installer detects existing product (due to upgrade code)
2. uninstall the old product
3. the service is not stopped/uninstalled due to a bug in 1.1 installer
4. 1.2 tries to replace the executable, but a process is still running the executable.

Note that I have tweaked the 1.1 installer using Orca to have a correct ServiceControl which stops and remove the service on uninstall. We call this **1.1tweaked**. If I install the product using **1.1tweaked** and then use my 1.2 installer than everything works as expected.

I have already tried any possible configuration of the ServiceControl in 1.2 installer, but it's useless if the steps above are right.

How can I force to stop the "current" Windows Service in the 1.2 installer?
It looks like I need a Custom Action. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: When did you schedule `RemoveExistingProducts`? It may work if you schedule it `afterInstallExecute` since the 1.1 installer will no longer try to uninstall the service due to component reference counting if your 1.1 install followed the suggested component rules.

Comment: @BrianSutherland I've not defined it, I'm relying MajorUpgrade I suppose. Are you suggesting to add `<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallExecute"/>` in the `<InstallExecuteSequence>`?

Comment: @BrianSutherland or better, use `Schedule="afterInstallExecute"` in the `MajorUpgrade`

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting exactly that. However, this can result in several issues if file versioning is not properly done since it will not update the files. This should work nicely if a bunch of "best practices" were followed but this is not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: If this doesn't work you may have to author a patch to the 1.1 msi using your 1.1tweaked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462231/msi-wix-creating-minor-upgrade-patch-by-using-2-msis). Or just put a message into your 1.2 installer telling the user to stop the service since you cannot make a deferred custom action to stop the service that runs before RemoveExistingProducts if you schedule RemoveExistingProducts any earlier.

Comment: @BrianSutherland Thanks for your help. I've decided to inform the user as other options seem too risky and not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments, these are the possible solutions:

- create a patch for the 1.1 installer following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462231/msi-wix-creating-minor-upgrade-patch-by-using-2-msis)
- use the attribute `Schedule="afterInstallExecute"` in the MajorUpgrade. This may work if the components are well defined and file are versioned correctly.
- inform the user to stop the service.